# React storybook - googleapis not working

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm using the google object (e.g. new google.maps.places.PlacesService()) in my React component. This is the component that I would like to test/optimize using Story book. In the story book config, I tried calling the googapis in the 'preview-head.html' as a script pointing to "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=....

However, when the story book is loading/started, my react component is throwing an exception "ReferenceError: google is not defined". Seems, the above api is not calling properly.

Appreciate your kind help.

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach works for me. Did you restart storybook since changing preview-head.html?

Comment: Interesting. I think I restarted after the changes. Let me check it again though. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, my bad. There's a typo in the script tag. It's working now after it's corrected. Thanks again, mpontus!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here is the correct answer in the latest version (6.0):

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-rendering

Add the googlescripts tag to your head by including it in `preview-head.html`